# XAMPP Localhost not working even though apache is working just fine

Tags: php, apache

I have tried many things, saw youtube videos, stack previous questions, but could'nt solve it.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Apache/2.4.48 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/7.3.29 Server at localhost Port 80
```

This is what comes up when I go for `localhost`.
I am using XAMPP, Apache is working, even I can access `localhost/phpmyadmin` through mysql, but not localhost.

Comment: It means Apache doesn't have permission to view the folder / default file at that location. Check what user account it runs under and what permission it has to the root folder / default file.

Comment: how do I check this?

Comment: You mean check which account apache runs under? Or check filesystem permissions? You should be able to search online to find instructions for both of these anyway